# Firebase Cloud Messages Push Notifications

Tags: firebase, notifications

I have developed a simple android app using Firebase database to store stuff.
Now, I want to set up notifications for each time a button is clicked.
Each time the button is clicked, it will take some info from firebase (text mostly) and will send a notification to anyone who downloaded the app.

I understood that simply creating a `notificationManager` won't work as needed.
I also heard about Firebase Cloud Messaging but im pretty new to this so I must know what I should start learning to make that work out.

So, if you have any good tutorials or anything helpful, that would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive for the FCM in android app. Refer this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple). And you need to can use database triggers in firebase cloud functions to send FCM notification, or you need to deploy a cloud http function to do so.